# TS: Get generic children typed individually

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine an escenario where some property type depends on the value of other property

e.g. There's a planet with only two countries, if your son borns in 'onename land', then his/her name should be a string; but if your son borns in 'twonames land', then his/her name should be two strings

```
const iPeople: { nationality: 'onename land' | 'twonames land', name: string | [string, string] }[] = [
  { nationality: 'onename land', name: 'Jon' },
  { nationality: 'twonames land', name: ['Jon', 'Snow'] }
]
```

for generic purposes...

```
const iSomeThings: { a: 'X' | 'Y', b: string | [string, string] }[] = [
  { a: 'X', b: 'lorem' },
  { a: 'Y', b: ['lorem', 'ipsum'] }
]
```

In both iSomeThing objects, 'b' inferred type is 'string | [string, string]' but for each, I want it to be either 'string' or '[string, string]', typed accordingly to the value of 'a'

```
iSomeThings[0].b // inferred type is "string | [string, string]" but I want it to be "string" since 'a' value is 'X'
iSomeThings[1].b // inferred type is "string | [string, string]" but I want it to be "[string, string]" since 'a' value is 'Y'
```

> I want the type of 'b' property to depend on the value of 'a' property

If the value of property 'a' is 'X', then the type of property 'b' should be a text 'string' and if the value of property 'a' is 'Y' then the type of property 'b' should be a text tuple '[string, string]'... let's do it:

```
type A = 'X' | 'Y'
type B<T extends A> = T extends 'X' ? string : T extends 'Y' ? [string, string] : never

interface ISomeThing<T extends A> {
  a: T
  b: B<T>
}

class SomeThing<T extends A> implements ISomeThing<T> {
  a: T
  b: B<T>

  constructor(private _iSomething: ISomeThing<T>) {
    this.a = this._iSomething.a
    this.b = this._iSomething.b
  }
}
```

usage example with arbitrary 'a' type:

```
const someThing1: SomeThing<'X'> = new SomeThing<'X'>({ a: 'X', b: 'lorem' })
const someThing2: SomeThing<'Y'> = new SomeThing<'Y'>({ a: 'Y', b: ['lorem', 'ipsum'] })
someThing1.b // ✅ type of b is 'string'
someThing2.b // ✅ type of b is '[string, string]'
```

usage example with generic 'a' type:

```
const someThing1: SomeThing<A> = new SomeThing<A>({ a: 'X', b: 'lorem' })
const someThing2: SomeThing<A> = new SomeThing<A>({ a: 'Y', b: ['lorem', 'ipsum'] })
someThing1.b // ❌ type of 'b' is 'string | [string, string]', but i'm expecting it to be 'string'
someThing2.b // ❌ type of 'b' is 'string | [string, string]', but i'm expecting it to be '[string, string]'
```

usage example with 'map' to set generic from each object

```
const iSomeThings: ISomeThing<A>[] = [{ a: 'X', b: 'lorem' }, { a: 'Y', b: ['lorem', 'ipsum'] }]
const someThings: SomeThing<A>[] = iSomeThings.map(iSomeThing => new SomeThing<typeof iSomeThing.a>(iSomeThing))

someThings[0].b // ❌ type of 'b' is 'string | [string, string]', but i'm expecting it to be 'string'
someThings[1].b // ❌ type of 'b' is 'string | [string, string]', but i'm expecting it to be '[string, string]'
```

alright, let me highlight what's going on

```
<typeof iSomeThing.a>
```

> ⚠️ Offtopic
>
> if I remove the 'typeof' keyword, the generic argument would be a
> value (e.g. 'X') when it needs a type to avoid TS error, so should I create a new type from the value of 'a'?

> ⚠️ Assumption
>
> type of 'a' is 'A' (both 'X' | 'Y'), that's why 'b' type is also both
> 'string | [string, string]', but to avoid losing focus on the question
> let's asume it is fixed, so now...

someThings[n] is going to use someThings parent type, ignoring individual children specific types, so... how should I manage to get children types working individually and accesible from the array?

Comment: There's quite a bit going on here and it would help if you split it up into different issues and only ask about one of them.  The first issue is that your type `{ a: 'X' | 'Y', b: string | [string, string] }` allows things you don't want; you really want to make it a discriminated union like `{a: "X", b: string} | {a: "Y", b: [string, string]}`.  That will allow the compiler to narrow based on `a`.  But then you're also annotating array types and expecting the compiler to remember which element is in which position of the array; but that's not how array types work.  If you want that you ...

Comment: ... need tuple types, and probably something to help them be inferred.  If I try to fix all those problems at once I get code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weXRKW).  But if I wanted to make an answer for it, that answer would be *very long* because there are too many pieces.  Could you please streamline the question to focus on one well-defined and demarcated topic?

Comment: @jcalz I just saw your [link](https://tsplay.dev/weXRKW), it should be posted as an answer... you are constructing an implicit dynamic type from object array, which sounds great to get around the problem! I also saw a challenge from it: can you tell me how can I get that type before it is generated so it can be use as method's return type and get benefit from it in other scope?

Comment: I'd be happy to post an answer with an explanation if you'd streamline the question as I asked.  Either the question is primarily about how to represent a single value of the relevant type (which would be a discriminated union) or you already know how to do that and you want to know how to have the compiler remember the order of elements in an array.  Those are two distinct issues which are only related because your code runs into both of them.

Comment: As for your challenge, I don't understand what you mean, but if you manage to fix the focus issue in the question you might be able to write out a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  Unless it's just a follow-up question, in which case it belongs in its own post.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz done  I've moved part of the question to "Offtopic" and "Assumption" sections to better to focus on well-defined and demarcated topic

Answer (score -1):

Meanwhile looking for a better solution (one with less overhead), I'll go with this approach

```
const iSomeThings: ISomeThing<A>[] = [{ a: 'X', b: 'lorem' }, { a: 'Y', b: ['lorem', 'ipsum'] }]
const someThings: (SomeThing<'X'> | SomeThing<'Y'> )[] = iSomeThings.map(iSomeThing => {
  if (iSomeThing.a === 'X') return new SomeThing<'X'>(iSomeThing as ISomeThing<'X'>)
  else if (iSomeThing.a === 'Y') return new SomeThing<'Y'>(iSomeThing as ISomeThing<'Y'>)
})

someThings.forEach(someThing => {
  switch (someThing.a) {
    case 'X':
      // ✅ someThing.value is string
      break;
    case 'Y':
      // ✅ someThing.value is [string, string]
      break;
  }
})
```

Comment: What does "overload" mean here?  Do you mean "overhead" maybe?

Comment: @jcalz that's right, just edited my answer, I meant to say overhead 